Building CXX object stuck at 50% on Raspberry Pi 3
I'm currently working with the Point-LIO algorithm for a LiDAR sensor made by Unitree and I need to record rosbags on a small board that can be part of a bigger construction rather than my laptop. The installation went flawlessly on my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04 through Windows Subsystem for Linux but on the Raspberry Pi 3 running Ubuntu 20.04 Server I'm having some hiccups.
Currently whenever I run catkin_make (as specified in the following installation tutorial https://github.com/unitreerobotics/point_lio_unilidar/tree/main) all goes well until it tries to build the unitree_lidar_ros_node.cpp.o.
[ 50%] Building CXX object unitree_lidar_ros/CMakeFiles/unitree_lidar_ros_node.dir/src/unitree_lidar_ros_node.cpp.o
Is the commandline it gets stuck on. I've run it multiple times and it stopped one time because of an out of memory error but all the other times it seemingly goes on forever. Any ideas?
I haven't tried anything yet since I can't find anything about it online.

Try this w/out compiled https://lindevs.com/install-precompiled-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/
